# OleDbDataAdapter - read tab delimited file

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0, oledb

(I don't need alternatives to OleDbDataAdapter.)

The code below finds and reads the file OK but the DGV has four columns (as expected) but all the data rows just have text in the first column.

```
    Dim sDir As String = "c:\temp\"
    Dim sConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & sDir & ";Extended Properties='text;HDR=Yes;FMT=TabDelimited';"
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    Using adapt As New OleDbDataAdapter(String.Format("SELECT TOP 100 * FROM robo.txt"), sConn)
        adapt.Fill(dt)
    End Using
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
```

I would think the Extended Properties would be the only requirement. I've tried add a Schema.ini to no avail - I don't think it is even being read as the column headers never match the schema.

The header row in the most successful pass used commas as separator - this resulted in four columns with the proper names but the tab separated data all in Col1. If I use tabs in the header row I get some system assign columns (3) which sort of corresponds to a data row with two commas.

What am I doing wrong?

---

Here are the first few rows with the tab character being replaced by `<tab>` . I since noticed that I have an extra column in the data. The fix to the header row below did not fix the problem - all data is dumped into the first field.

Use a tab separator in the header, instead of commas, results in all header text and the data being dumped into the first field.

```
col1,state,col3,size,path
<tab>          same<tab><tab>  102912<tab>\\APCD04T\Data\Thumbs.db
<tab>          same<tab><tab>   22016<tab>\\APCD04T\Data\APCD Topical Info\APCD_Boards&Committees_List.doc
<tab>          same<tab><tab>   4.3 m<tab>\\APCD04T\Data\APCD Topical Info\LOSSAN-LAtoSLORailCorridorStrategicPlan.pdf
```

Comment: can you [edit] your post to show the first 2-3 lines of the file being read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learned several things while trying to load a `RoboCopy` log into a `DataTable` using OLEDB.

- log file needs to have a .txt or .csv (or ?) extension, .log fails.
- Schema.ini seems to be needed for tab delimited robocopy log, good for column definition anyway.
- Datagridview takes a long time to display 30MB of data so I used
  filters
- I borrowed code from the net to create a Schema.ini as noted below

(SO bug: code will not paste from Visual Studio anymore. Code tool flips to other web page for Java.)

```vb
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try
            Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
            'http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html can suppress header and summary 
            Dim sFile As String = "c:\temp\robo.txt" ' seems to need a .txt or .csv, .log didn't work
            CreateRoboLogSchema(sFile) ' recreates each pass, no needed once things work
            Dim sConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(sFile) & ";Extended Properties='text';"
            ' use Schema.ini for: HDR=Yes;FMT=TabDelimited' and column definitions
            Dim dt As New DataTable()
            Dim SQL As String = "SELECT * FROM " & IO.Path.GetFileName(sFile)
            'SQL &= " WHERE State <> 'Same'"
            Using adapt As New OleDbDataAdapter(SQL, sConn)
                adapt.Fill(dt)
            End Using
            Debug.Print("|" & dt.Rows(0)(1) & "|") ' show import trimmed leading spaces (trims trailing too)
            ' DGV slow to load large files, use filter to display target rows
            Dim dv As New DataView(dt)
            dv.RowFilter = "State <> 'Same'" ' not case sensitive
            DataGridView1.DataSource = dv
            DataGridView1.Columns(0).Visible = False
            DataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Finally
            'Cursor=Cursors.Default
        End Try
    End Sub
    Private Function CreateRoboLogSchema(ByVal strFileName As String) As Boolean
        ' edit http://www.vb-tips.com/CSVDataSet.aspx
        Dim ascii As System.Text.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII
        Dim swSchema As System.IO.StreamWriter = Nothing
        Dim blnReturn As Boolean
        Dim strSchemaPath As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(strFileName)
        Try
            strSchemaPath = IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(strFileName) & "\Schema.ini"
            swSchema = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(strSchemaPath, False, ascii)
            Dim strFile As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(strFileName)
            swSchema.WriteLine("[" & IO.Path.GetFileName(strFileName) & "]")
            swSchema.WriteLine("ColNameHeader=False")
            swSchema.WriteLine("Format=TabDelimited")
            swSchema.WriteLine("Col1=Value1 Text") ' file specific
            swSchema.WriteLine("Col2=State  Text")
            swSchema.WriteLine("Col3=DirChanges  Text")
            swSchema.WriteLine("Col4=Size  Text")
            swSchema.WriteLine("Col5=Filepath Text")
            'Continue for all fields 
            blnReturn = True
        Catch ex As Exception
            blnReturn = False
        Finally
            If swSchema IsNot Nothing Then
                swSchema.Close()
            End If
        End Try
        Return blnReturn
    End Function
```